# Environment NiceTabular returns an error in nicematrix.sty file

Tags: nicematrix

I am testing the NiceMatrix package and I am running this very simple code. The NiceTabular code  was copied from the documentation for this package. The preamble has some other standard packages.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}c!{\qquad}ccc!{\qquad}ccc@{}}
\toprule
& \Block{1-3}{First group} & & & \Block{1-3}{Second group} \\
Rank & 1A & 1B & 1C & 2A & 2B & 2C \\
\midrule
1 & 0.657 & 0.913 & 0.733 & 0.830 & 0.387 & 0.893\\
2 & 0.343 & 0.537 & 0.655 & 0.690 & 0.471 & 0.333\\
3 & 0.783 & 0.885 & 0.015 & 0.306 & 0.643 & 0.263\\
4 & 0.161 & 0.708 & 0.386 & 0.257 & 0.074 & 0.336\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

When I try to typeset the document I get the following error:

> nicematrix.sty:5548:Undefined control sequence. l. 5548
> \seq_set_map_x:NNn

I have the latest version of the nicematrix package and associated packages like tikz. I am running the code on the latest version of TeXShop having updated all packages with TeXLive (operating system is MacOS Mojave 10.14.6).

I am sure its a package related issue but I cannot understand what is missing.

Comment: works ok for me (apart from the undefined \toprule\midrule). So probably something is not up-to-date. `\seq_set_map_x:NNn` is from 2020-07-16.

Comment: I can confirm, once you load ``booktabs`` too, everything wokrs fine, no errors or warnings

Comment: (I'm the author of  `nicematrix`). `\seq_set_map_x:NNn` is a command of `expl3` and `expl3` is now integrated in the LaTeX kernel. I think that your LaTeX kernel (and the corresponding format) is not up-to-date even if the packages are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer F. Pantigny. You are right, it was an issue with the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: How did you solve the problem with the LaTex kernel? I am having a similar error...

Comment: Updated LaTeX installation; as @f-pantigny stated the packages were up to date but the LaTeX installation needed updating.